# Site does not load web font

Tags: sass, fonts, path, font-face, webfonts

I've searched all over the internet, but the answer is probably bullshit. I'm having a problem uploading my web font to my site (the console always returns an error saying it can't download the font).It's probably a path problem, I don't know.

[This is an example of an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lKot.png)

This is where I retrieve the font in my SCSS file.

[my SCSS file path is wp-content/themes/whitebat/resources/sass/app.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdbcL.png)

The path to the fonts is wp-content/themes/whitebat/fonts/fonts.woff

The browser load always a system fonts. Help!

I've tried multiple times to change the path, but for some stupid reason, it never works

Comment: Actually read the URL.

Answer (score 0):

- Check file permissions: Make sure that the font file has the correct
  permissions set. On most web servers, the font file should have read
  permissions for the web server user. If the file permissions are
  incorrect, the web server may not be able to access the file.
- Check CORS settings: If you're loading the font from a different
  domain than your website, make sure that the other domain has set the
  appropriate CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers to allow
  your website to access the font file.
- Check the font file itself: Make sure that the font file is not
  corrupted or damaged in any way. You can try downloading the font
  file again from a trusted source and re-uploading it to your website.

Comment: It's none of these things - He's referencing the wrong URL. It's visible in the screenshot.